Dialation of a convex set covers its mirror
Problem: Let $C\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact convex set. Prove that the mirror image of $C$
can be covered by a suitable translate of $C$ blown up by the factor of $d$;
that is, there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $-C \subset x + dC$.
My attempt: I guess the intended proof is some clever usage of Helly's theorem. I tried expressing the condition as the existence of a point in an intersection of convex sets but failed.
I guess even a solution for $d=2$ would be blessed.
This is taken from Matousek's Lectures in Discrete Geometry (1.3.6).

Here is an old question, apparently without an answer but with an important hint inside the question. Does that make sense?

It's only half the solution, but yes it's very helpful. Thank you

We assume the given set $C$ is a polytope and then any convex set could be formally approximated as a polytope and the problem will follow (I will leave the details for the reader).
Like the referenced link in the comments suggests start by defining: $\forall s\in C:A_{s}:=\left\{ v\in\mathbb{R}^{d}:-s\in dS+v\right\}$
In other words this is the set of all the translations that will cover the mirror of the point $s$.
The problem then becomes proving: $\bigcap_{s\in C}A_{s}\neq\emptyset$.
Furthermore, since $C$ is a convex polytope, it's enough to prove: $\bigcap_{s\in ver(C)}A_{s}\neq\emptyset$. where $ver(C)$ are the vertices of $C$. We proceed by finding a certain point in $\bigcap_{s\in ver(C)}A_{s}$:
Denote the vertices of $C$ $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Note that $A_{x_{1}}$ is a mirrored and translated copy of $dC$, and $A_{x_{i}}=A_{x_{1}}+(x_i-x_1)$. Denote the vertices of $A_{x_{1}}$ by $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. I claim that the point $p=\frac{1}{d}\left(X_{i_{2}}+X_{i_{3}}+\ldots+X_{i_{d+1}}\right)$
is inside the following sets: $A_{1},A_{i_{2}},A_{i_{3}},\ldots,A_{i_{d+1}}$
Of course it's inside $A_1$ as a convex combination of its vertices. I will show it's in $A_{i_{2}}$ but from symmetry the rest will follow. Indeed one can write:$p=\frac{1}{d}\left(\frac{d-1}{d}X_{1}+\frac{1}{d}X_{i_{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{d}\left(X_{i_{3}}+\frac{1}{d}X_{i_{2}}-\frac{1}{d}X_{1}\right)+\frac{1}{d}\left(X_{i_{4}}+\frac{1}{d}X_{i_{2}}-\frac{1}{d}X_{1}\right)+\ldots+\frac{1}{d}\left(X_{i_{d+1}}+\frac{1}{d}X_{i_{2}}-\frac{1}{d}X_{1}\right)$
which is a convex combination of the vertices of $A_{i_{2}}$ as we wanted.
Also, note that there is nothing special about $A_1$ the same is true for $A_2$ and $A_3$ and so on. Thus, we have shown every $d+1$ sets intersect. From Helly's theorem they all intersect together. Hence there is a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying all the required conditions. Q.E.D
